# Tree table plugin won't show child nodes properly if parent has more children than page size

Tags: javascript, webix, treetable

First of all, I'm not insistent for using webix, any javascript tree table plugin that supports dynamic paging for both child and parent nodes can help me. However, it would be great if I can find a solution based on webix.

I am using this tree table for huge data. For tests, I have a 10 size webix treetable. When I click a parent node, not all of child nodes are shown.

See below image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsXu7.jpg

Below show webix config:

```
   grid = webix.ui({
        container: "tableResults",
        view: "treetable",
        id: "treetable",
        columns: @Html.Raw(columnsArr),
        url: "/GridTree/GetGridTree?&parent=@(Model)&count=10",
        datafetch: 10,
        pager: {
            template: "{common.first()} {common.prev()} {common.pages()} {common.next()} {common.last()}",
            container: "paging",
            size: 10,
            group: 10,
        },
        //autoheight: true,
        height: 500,
        select: "row", multiselect: true,
        resizeColumn: true,
        dragColumn: "order",
        filterMode: {
            level: 1,
            showSubItems: false,
            openParents: false
        },
        leftSplit: 2,
        rightSplit: 1
});
```

There are 10 kids for the parent 90203050, but I can only see 6 of them because there are 10 serial no in total. I want to show child nodes by paging as same as parents.

Webix [in this example](https://snippet.webix.com/y4ybokph) seems to work properly, however parent nodes are not loaded by dynamic paging.

Comment: I don't think we can help you, until you show us some piece of your code

Comment: @LeoOdishvili I've added some js code if it helps..